# Are zero and one considered as literals in mathematical logic?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

[Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(mathematical_logic))

> In mathematical logic, a literal is an atomic formula (atom) or its negation [...] Literals can be divided into two types:

> A positive literal is just an atom (e.g., x).

> A negative literal is the negation of an atom (e.g., ¬x).

[Stanford.edu](http://thue.stanford.edu/bool.html)

> An atom of a Boolean algebra is an element x such that there exist exactly two elements y satisfying y ≤ x, namely x and 0

From the above definitions, can the Boolean values `1` and `0` be considered as positive and negative literals respectively?

If `0` and `1` are not literals, how  can they be called?

Comment: $0$ and $1$ are commonly referred to as "truth values". I also think "1" does fall into the definition of atom above.

Comment: @Vasya You are right. Both `0` and `1` satisfy the definition of atom. I edited the last part.

Comment: In some presentation of math log we can have the two "constants": $\bot$ (False) and $\top$ (True). This means that we can have the formula $p \lor \bot$. Obviously, they have fixed truth value.

Comment: And they are elements of $\Omega_0$, and therefore "operators of arity zero" in [propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Generic_description_of_a_propositional_calculus). I like "truth value" way better.

Comment: The meaning of the term "atom" in the second quote is totally unrelated to how "atom" is used in the first quote.